# SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync() does not work on iOS

Tags: c#, ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

I have the following piece of code :

```
 SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(1);
 GameObject.Find("Canvas").transform.FindChild("Loading").gameObject.SetActive(true);
```

When building from Xcode to a iPhone running on iOS 10.1 the loading game object gets enabled and then nothing happens. The level does not load at all. Xcode throws no errors and I also get no errors or exceptions from the unity console( both in editor and on device). Has anyone encountered this before? How do I fix it ?

Edit: Sometimes it works just as expected. After stopping and starting the app several times from XCode.

Comment: Please post reasonable amount of code so it is clear what you use to wait for operation completion.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov This is all the relevant code. Its used in a method that is called from a button click that loads the scene. It works on PC and android and from the editor.

Comment: Is the scene added to the Build Settings? There should be at-lease 2 scenes. Scene with 0 index and Scene with 1 index. If this is true then what is your Unity and iOS version?

Comment: Yes all scenes are added to the build settings. There is a exception throw if you try to load a scene not added there and like I said there are no exceptions. iOS version is mention in the question and unity version is 5.5.01a

Comment: Haven't heard about this problem before. Looked to see if there is any bug report but couldn't find one.Those times that it fails to work,  are you sure that `SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(1);` is being executed at-all? You can use `Debug.Log` to find out. Also, instead of running it from the Editor, open it from the iOS device itself and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: @UriPopov have you found the solution yet? I'm facing the same issue. When my app is launched for 1st time from xcode, the scene is loaded as expected, but when I  restart the app, the scene is not loaded!